# HighCharts Angular - Setting chart data from API

Tags: angular, typescript, api, http, highcharts

I'm trying to set the data property of my chart to values coming from this API: https://bgpie.net/api/rrc/00/mostfrequentstatefrequencycdf.

I've created an Interface reflecting it:

```
export interface ChartData{
    item1: number;
    item2: number;
}
```

And this is my chart

```
chartOptions: Options = {
    title: {
      text: 'CDF of the most frequent update frequency',
      style: {
        color: 'whitesmoke'
      }
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'line',
      zoomType: 'x',
      backgroundColor: '#323232',
    },

    ...

    series: [],

    ...

  };
```

I'm trying to set the data property (which is inside the series property) to the values I get from the API. Note the the data property can be hard coded like this:

```
series: [
  {
   data: [[1,2], [2,4] [3,7] ...]
```

With the first value of the couple being the x-axis value and the second being the y-axis value, the same goes for ChartData: item1 is the x-axis value, item2 is the y-axis value. This is my attempt:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.chartService.getMostFrequentUpdateData().subscribe(
      (data: ChartData[]) => {
    this.chartOptions.series = [
          {
            name: 'ao',
            type: 'line',
            data: data,
            color: '#009879',
          }
        ];
        });
}
```

I get the following error: Type 'ChartData[]' is not assignable to type '(number | PointOptionsObject | [string | number, number | null] | null)[]'.   Type 'ChartData' is not assignable to type 'number | PointOptionsObject | [string | number, number | null] | null'.     Type 'ChartData' is not assignable to type '[string | number, number | null]'.

I can't assign ChartData[] to the data property.

I do realize while writing this that ChartData contains two numbers but it should be an ARRAY containing two numbers to match the data type, I'm thinking that's the problem but I don't know how to solve it. Just for clarity this is the http call in my service

```
getMostFrequentUpdateData(): Observable<ChartData[]>{
    return this.http.get<ChartData[]>('https://bgpie.net/api/rrc/00/mostfrequentstatefrequencycdf');
  }
```

and this is a github repository containing the project https://github.com/mauri5566/sitocopy/blob/master/src/app/components/home/modal-most-frequent-update/modal-most-frequent-update.component.ts (Unfortunately it contains some merge conflicts)

**EDIT:**
I've made a new attempt based on the suggestion of Karol Kołodziej but it still won't show the data. I've checked with a console.log and `chartData` receives the following values:

```
0: (2) [0, 0]
1: (2) [1, 98.60093378412567]
2: (2) [2, 99.69295521976126]
3: (2) [3, 99.79668345638125]
4: (2) [5, 99.87971204489524]
5: (2) [7, 99.92847121598932]
6: (2) [10, 99.97148048483176]
7: (2) [14, 99.98068032843442]
8: (2) [20, 99.9903401642172]
9: (2) [29, 99.99172014075761]
10: (2) [40, 99.99356010947814]
11: (2) [57, 99.99402010165828]
12: (2) [80, 99.99977000390994]
```

The way these values are set seem to be correct, it's an array of couples. The chartData interface is still set the same way and this is how I set the `ngOnInit`:

```
chartDataX: number[] = [];
chartDataY: number[] = [];
chartData: any[] = [];

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.chartService.getMostFrequentUpdateData().subscribe(
      (data: ChartData[]) => {
        for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
          this.chartDataX.push(data[i].item1);
          this.chartDataY.push(data[i].item2);
          this.chartData.push([this.chartDataX[i], this.chartDataY[i]])
        }
      });

        this.chartOptions.series = [
          {
            name: 'ao',
            type: 'line',
            data: this.chartData,
            color: '#009879',
          }
        ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your suspicion is correct, the data passed to the series should be:

- `Array<number>`,
- `Array<Array<number>>` or
- `Array<Object>` where in object you have at least `x` and `y`.

How data should look like: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data

In order to fix that I suggest, you should create two arrays `item1` and `item2`. And while you fetch that data, push points accordingly to each array. Then pass that to the chart.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I've followed your suggestion but the data is still not shown although I don't get any errors. I've updated my question to show what changes I've made

Comment: If you initiate that series in the `chartOptions` then in the `ngOnInit` you might assign the new data to the existing series. Demo:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-qscjmp